# I want to update my checkbox using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html table with the following field: Job Completed

I would like to put a checkbox on each row of the completed column only using php amd HTML.

I want the value of yes/no to be store in my mysql database.

My MySQL table has a table called data with a row called job, I just can’t get this to work, my MySQL table has empty values as well.

//html table

```
<td width="93" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Job Completed</strong></td>
```

I also have my results section

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" value="yes"/></td>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: My question is: why won’t my checkbox remember the value I apply if I check this box, close my browser down and go back to this page. What have a done wrong, any advice is appreciated, and maybe I am tired. 

The explanation to my problem is detailed above.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>]" value="no"/><input type="checkbox" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>]" value="yes"/>

Comment: What you can do is do an if else statement. first retrieve results from the database row, job. if job == name of checkbox, echo yes else echo no.

Answer (score 0):

You need some more information on how you are saving the jobs to the database.

Since you have not specified the columns in your mysql data table. I can only guess that you have a column called "isComplete" or something like that. If you do not have a column in the mysql table, you will have to add one.

Another problem to clear up before you begin saving, you are not checking the check box properly. The attribute "checked" should be used instead of value="yes". For example, to check the box when the page is loaded, the input should be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>]" checked />
```

Are you posting the whole form to save, or are you just saving the changes to checkbox? If you are posting the whole form, the page that handles the posted form will have to save the value of the checkbox. If you just want to save just the checkbox changes, you will have to create a page that updates the "isComplete" column in the database, and call that page using javascript and ajax everytime the checkbox value is changed.

Once, you have the value saving in the database you will use php to check the checkbox when the page loads based on the database value. Something like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>]" <?php if ($result['isComplete']) {echo 'checked';} ?>/></td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is missing a closing square bracket

Comment: I added in the missing square bracket. Thanks.